# How to get Https URL content

Tags: url, https, request, server-side

I have a https link that requires user login & password. If I run it in FX like this:
https://usernameassword@www.example.com/link/sublink

it will return the xml data as expected.

However, what i'm trying to do, is to automate this process.
I try to use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in PHP.

I even tried to use AJAX, but still doesn't work.

I tried to get the content (XML) either in Server or in the front-end (ajax), but both don't work.

Does anyone know what I need to go in order to get the content? Do I need to obtain the SSL certificate?

Solution in any ohter languages will be welcome too.

Comment: What is FX? and there's a little typo in there, "usernameassword"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) via its [Java bindings](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use curl library, also certificate should be verified if you want to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. Or just ignore it using curl options.

Answer (score 1):

cURL or wget with SSL support.

cURL, you can run either through the compiled PHP library or call the executable from PHP.

Wget, you will have to call the executable.